# Setting reverse geocoding language in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, reverse-geocoding, internationalization

I'm trying to reverse geocode some points and get their addresses with ArcGIS Pro.

There are points all around the world and for many of them, addresses returned is in local language (Greek, Thai, Chinese...)

Is it possible to get addresses in English for all?

I saw that it's possible with the Python API to set a language but I can't find a way with ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of the output field.